# Reading a CSV file in Pandas not working properly with sep='\t'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files from an HPLC, when doing a standard import via pandas.read_csv I get something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

#get files from folder, careful, case sensitive

files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
df = pd.read_csv(files[0])
```

```
0   Application Name\tLabSolutions
1   Version\t5.93
2   Data File Name\tC:\LabSolutions\Data\outreach\...
3   Output Date\t11/12/2023
4   Output Time\t3:03:23 PM
```

But when trying to change the separator to a tab
`df = pd.read_csv(files[0], sep='\t')`

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-627-dc81386f301e> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 
      7 files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
----> 8 df = pd.read_csv(files[0], sep='\t')
      9 df

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 73, saw
```

What might be going wrong?

The files are a bit weirdly structured with sections defined like this.

```
[File Information]
Type    Data File
Generated   11/12/2023 9:51:47 AM
Generated by    Lab2
Modified    11/12/2023 2:58:18 PM
Modified by Lab2
```

and

```
[Configuration]
Instrument Name S24564-Instrument1
Instrument #    1
Line #  1
# of Detectors  2
Detector ID Detector A  Detector B
Detector Name   Detector A  Detector
# of Channels   2   1
```

There are several different blocks like this, with varying rows and columns of data.

Another option would be to somehow grab each [section] of each file but I have even less idea how to approach that.

I lost count of what I have tried and I don't see how this could lead to an error, all I am doing is asking to use a tab instead of comma as separator.

Comment: Is there really a tab in the file or ist it just the string "\t".

Comment: Can you share part of the file? The example you have posted are not csv formatted. It looks more like configuration file, a YAML of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

From the error, line 73 of your file has only one field, thus a `\t` is not there.

For having more details, I would use the `on_bad_lines` argument like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

#get files from folder, careful, case sensitive

files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
df = pd.read_csv(files[0], on_bad_lines='warn')
```

You should be able to have a dataframe and to have in your logs, lines with warings (but I guess the error will be the same than previously).

The documentation of the `on_bad_lines` argument:

> on_bad_lines{‘error’, ‘warn’, ‘skip’} or Callable, default ‘error’
>
> Specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields). Allowed values are :
>
> - 'error', raise an Exception when a bad line is encountered.
> - 'warn', raise a warning when a bad line is encountered and skip that line.
> - 'skip', skip bad lines without raising or warning when they are encountered.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to deal with this is to read the file into pandas with no separator and then split the resultant single column on `\t`. If desired, you can then drop any rows which don't have two values (such as the section headers like `[Configuration]`):

```py
df = pd.read_csv(files[0])
df = df[0].str.split('\t', expand=True)
df = df.dropna(subset=[1])
```

Note I've assumed no header in the csv file, hence the original column will be labelled `0`; it that's not the case, just substitute the actual column name in its place. Following the `dropna` you can then rename the columns as desired.

Note also that it looks like you may have some lines with more than one tab separator in them, in which case the `split` will generate more than two columns. If you don't want that, specify `n=1` to limit to one split:

```py
df = df[0].str.split('\t', n=1, expand=True)
```